# How to Click on a Text in Selenium Webdriver 2.x

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

I am not able to click on the below HTML values through selenium webdriver click command through Java.

Here's my HTML...I have to click on *PAAcctAcctRels*, *PAAcctActivityData*, etc. as in the HTML.

I tried with LinkText (`driver.findElement(By.linkText("PAAcctAcctRels")).click();`) and xpath (`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='primaryNavLevel2Z6_G868H4S0K881F0AAEO37LG28N0']/div[1]/a")).click();`)

```
<div id="primaryNavLevel2Z6_0G5A11K0KGF200AIUB98T20G52" class="dropdown_1columns">
  <div class="col_1">
    <a class="" href="?uri=nm:oid:Z6_0G5A11K0KGF200AIUB98T20G53">
      <strong>
        <span lang="en" dir="ltr">
          PAAcctAcctRels
          <span class="wpthemeAccess"> currently selected</span>
        </span>
      </strong>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_1">
    <a class="" href="?uri=nm:oid:Z6_0G5A11K0KGF200AIUB98T20GD4">
      <span lang="en" dir="ltr">PAAcctActivityData</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_1">
    <a class="" href="?uri=nm:oid:Z6_0G5A11K0KGF200AIUB98T20GT1">
      <span lang="en" dir="ltr">PAAcctAddrEmail</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Is there any other way to do this..please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

**1-** For **Clicking on text 'PAAcctActivityData'**, you can use the below code:

**`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='PAAcctActivityData']")).click();`**

**2-** For **Clicking on text 'PAAcctAddrEmail**', you can use the below code:

**`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='PAAcctAddrEmail']")).click();`**

**NOTE:-** The above xpaths will locate the`span elements` with exact innerHTML/text as `'PAAcctActivityData'` or `'PAAcctAddrEmail'`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`By.linkText("PAAcctAcctRels")` won't work because that link has more text (ie ' `currently selected`'), and the problem with your xpath is that is starts with **.**`//`

The following should work (I have avoided using * for performance)

```
By.xpath("//div[@id='primaryNavLevel2Z6_G868H4S0K881F0AAEO37LG28N0']/div[1]/a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using //[@id='primaryNavLevel2Z6_G868H4S0K881F0AAEO37LG28N0']/div[1]/a/span
as xpath. Remove the initial '.' and add '/span' at the end.